# PHP Echo content from and array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

Hi I was wondering if someone out there could help me with some php syntax..

So I have this:

```
<?php echo $post->image; ?>
```

which shows out the array:

```
[image] => {
"type":"image",
"title":"websitehere_Vogue_swatches12.png",
"mime":"image/png",
"url":"http://websitehere.co.za/images/easyblog_images/983/websitehere_Vogue_swatches12.png",
```

From here I need to just echo the url value from

```
"url":"http://websitehere.co.za/images/easyblog_images/983/websitehere_Vogue_swatches12.png",
```

Thanks
A

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez, even better: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @FirstOne Edit gets my vote!

Comment: You `echo` an array? Hmm..

Comment: To be clear, what's the result of `var_dump($post->image);`?

Answer (score 1):

Just access the `url` property of it.

```
echo $post->image->url;
```

Comment: Ok now this is getting spooky, again with the beat me by 50 milli seconds

Comment: Race you to the next question!